# rust-openssl can't build bin when --target=i386-apple-ios (iOS simulator)

Tags: ios, xcode, openssl, rust, cross-compiling

I have a multi module project that contains a rlib (depends on rust-openssl) and a bin (depends on rlib).

It is ok when I build rlib alone, but failed when I build bin, I got error:

```
...
ld: warning: URGENT: building for OSX, but linking in object file (/Users/travis/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/i386-apple-ios/lib/liballoc_jemalloc-ea49ffd3fee5264c.rlib(pages.pic.o)) built for iOS. Note: This will be an error in the future.
          ld: warning: URGENT: building for OSX, but linking in object file (/Users/travis/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/i386-apple-ios/lib/liballoc_jemalloc-ea49ffd3fee5264c.rlib(quarantine.pic.o)) built for iOS. Note: This will be an error in the future.
          ld: warning: URGENT: building for OSX, but linking in object file (/Users/travis/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/i386-apple-ios/lib/liballoc_jemalloc-ea49ffd3fee5264c.rlib(rtree.pic.o)) built for iOS. Note: This will be an error in the future.
          Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
            "_fputs$UNIX2003", referenced from:
                _write_string in libopenssl_sys-f183dd940b82d26e.rlib(ui_openssl.o)
                _read_string in libopenssl_sys-f183dd940b82d26e.rlib(ui_openssl.o)
            "_fopen$UNIX2003", referenced from:
                _open_console in libopenssl_sys-f183dd940b82d26e.rlib(ui_openssl.o)
                _openssl_fopen in libopenssl_sys-f183dd940b82d26e.rlib(o_fopen.o)
            "_strerror$UNIX2003", referenced from:
                _openssl_strerror_r in libopenssl_sys-f183dd940b82d26e.rlib(o_str.o)
            "_fwrite$UNIX2003", referenced from:
                _file_write in libopenssl_sys-f183dd940b82d26e.rlib(bss_file.o)
                _file_puts in libopenssl_sys-f183dd940b82d26e.rlib(bss_file.o)
                _read_string in libopenssl_sys-f183dd940b82d26e.rlib(ui_openssl.o)
                _read_string_inner in libopenssl_sys-f183dd940b82d26e.rlib(ui_openssl.o)
                _test_rc4_init_key in libopenssl_sys-f183dd940b82d26e.rlib(eng_openssl.o)
          ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
...
```

[log on travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/chshawkn/rust-openssl-demo/builds/235487913#L679)

Target i386-apple-ios failed.
Target aarch64-apple-ios armv7-apple-ios armv7s-apple-ios ok.

I tried adding

```
[target.i386-apple-ios]
rustflags = [
"-C", "link-arg=-mios-simulator-version-min=7.0.0"
]
```

into ~/.cargo/config and ended with another error like this:

```
ld: warning: URGENT: building for iOS simulator, but linking in object file (/Users/user/project/target/i386-apple-ios/debug/deps/libopenssl_sys-9f3b06cb5b388503.rlib(wp-mmx.o)) built for OSX. Note: This will be an error in the future.
          ld: warning: object file (/Users/user/project/target/i386-apple-ios/debug/deps/libopenssl_sys-9f3b06cb5b388503.rlib(wp-mmx.o)) was built for newer OSX version (10.12) than being linked (7.0)
          Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
            "_fputs$UNIX2003", referenced from:
                _write_string in libopenssl_sys-9f3b06cb5b388503.rlib(ui_openssl.o)

  process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name ssurl src/bin/ssurl.rs --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=e779ded66ad6a046 -C extra-filename=-e779ded66ad6a046 --out-dir /Users/user/project/target/i386-apple-ios/debug/deps --target i386-apple-ios -L dependency=/Users/user/project/target/i386-apple-ios/debug/deps -L dependency=/Users/user/project/target/debug/deps --extern serde_json=/Users/user/project/target/i386-apple-ios/debug/deps/libserde_json-a20ebb8bb7b96947.rlib --extern birdcrypto=/Users/user/project/target/i386-apple-ios/debug/deps/libbirdcrypto-7b7f8b4d9b356742.rlib --extern tokio_io=/Users/user/project/target/i386-apple-ios/debug/deps/libtokio_io-ffe06c22ad81dd5f.rlib --extern bytes=/Users/user/project/target/i386-apple-ios/debug/deps/libbytes-3515e9da1291588d.rlib --extern qrcode=/Users/user/project/target/i386-apple-ios/debug/deps/libqrcode-0b5b9eed05c8d5fb.rlib --extern net2=/Users/user/project/target/i386-apple-ios/debug/deps/libnet2-ecef00d50a8ddca3.rlib --extern lru_cache=/Users/user/project/target/i386-apple-ios/debug/deps/liblru_cache-3a583fd605a1b3b3.rlib --extern tokio_core=/Users/user/project/target/i386-apple-ios/debug/deps/libtokio_core-57e0150d22448791.rlib --extern byteorder=/Users/user/project/target/i386-apple-ios/debug/deps/libbyteorder-240cc8a1e1423fad.rlib --extern domain=/Users/user/project/target/i386-apple-ios/debug/deps/libdomain-fc3ea0606d179f92.rlib --extern futures=/Users/user/project/target/i386-apple-ios/debug/deps/libfutures-8985671f9fa6f7b8.rlib --extern time=/Users/user/project/target/i386-apple-ios/debug/deps/libtime-65bf99b4b8c3df95.rlib --extern log=/Users/user/project/target/i386-apple-ios/debug/deps/liblog-d4c0e5c2504fbbea.rlib --extern base64=/Users/user/project/target/i386-apple-ios/debug/deps/libbase64-3733960102cc46b7.rlib --extern env_logger=/Users/user/project/target/i386-apple-ios/debug/deps/libenv_logger-8778ad732965ba61.rlib --extern num_cpus=/Users/user/project/target/i386-apple-ios/debug/deps/libnum_cpus-9b2a7df0e5b9fd16.rlib --extern clap=/Users/user/project/target/i386-apple-ios/debug/deps/libclap-95e5c3504e3f13b5.rlib --extern birdnet=/Users/user/project/target/i386-apple-ios/debug/deps/libbirdnet-baa74095bd0c6dca.rlib -C link-arg=-mios-simulator-version-min=7.0.0 -L native=/Users/user/project/tmp/openssl-1.1.0e-i386-apple-ios/lib -L native=/Users/user/project/target/i386-apple-ios/debug/build/rust-crypto-38b42e435c8bcaf2/out` (exit code: 101)               _read_string in libopenssl_sys-9f3b06cb5b388503.rlib(ui_openssl.o)
            "_fopen$UNIX2003", referenced from:
                _open_console in libopenssl_sys-9f3b06cb5b388503.rlib(ui_openssl.o)
                _openssl_fopen in libopenssl_sys-9f3b06cb5b388503.rlib(o_fopen.o)
            "_strerror$UNIX2003", referenced from:
                _openssl_strerror_r in libopenssl_sys-9f3b06cb5b388503.rlib(o_str.o)
            "_fwrite$UNIX2003", referenced from:
                _file_write in libopenssl_sys-9f3b06cb5b388503.rlib(bss_file.o)
                _file_puts in libopenssl_sys-9f3b06cb5b388503.rlib(bss_file.o)
                _read_string in libopenssl_sys-9f3b06cb5b388503.rlib(ui_openssl.o)
                _read_string_inner in libopenssl_sys-9f3b06cb5b388503.rlib(ui_openssl.o)
                _test_rc4_init_key in libopenssl_sys-9f3b06cb5b388503.rlib(eng_openssl.o)
          ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[demo project to reproduce the error](https://github.com/chshawkn/rust-openssl-demo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems.

1. symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
   After replace openssl static lib from https://github.com/chshawkn/openssl-build to https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone, target i386-apple-ios built successfully.
2. le (/Users/user/project/target/i386-apple-ios/debug/deps/libopenssl_sys-9f3b06cb5b388503.rlib(wp-mmx.o)) built for OSX.
   Put a script at ~/.cargo/bin/cc to fix this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ -n "$(echo $@ | grep i386-apple-ios)" ] || [ -n "$(echo $@ | grep 
x86_64-apple-ios)" ]; then
  xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-path
  exec xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator cc -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0.0 $*
elif [ -n "$(echo $@ | grep apple-ios)" ]; then
  xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path
  exec xcrun --sdk iphoneos cc -mios-version-min=7.0.0 $*
else
  exec /usr/bin/cc $*
fi
```